# How can I continuously read from the serial port in a Perl Win32::GUI program?

Tags: perl, user-interface, winapi, serial-port

I would like to use the [Win32::SerialPort](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::SerialPort) module under Windows XP to read a text string from a COM port.

There is a scale attached to the serial port which continuously sends the current measured weight. Since I'm also using [Win32::GUI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::GUI) I need a way to read that non-blocking. What's the best way to do this? Should I use `Lookfor` or `streamline`? I'm a little confused by the documentation.

---

> **Original question text:** Ich möchte mit dem Modul Win32::SerialPort unter Windows Xp von einem COM-Port ein bestimmten Textstring nur einlesen. An dem SerialPort ist eine Waage angeschlossen, die permanent das aktuell gemessene Gewicht ausgibt. Da ich auch Win32::GUI verwende darf/sollte das einlesen nicht blockierend sein. Wie stelle ich das am geschicktesten an? Was sollte ich verwenden Lookfor oder streamline? Ich blicke bei dem Manual nicht so richtig durch.

Comment: Es wäre eine gute Idee diese Frage auf Englisch neu zu formulieren wenn du eine Antwort erwartest... SO ist eine Englisch geprägte Community. ;-)

Comment: @MhR: Die Ubersetzung scheint gut mir. Aber meine Deutche ist nicht sehr gut.... :-)

Comment: The translation is excellent.

Comment: That's interesting; I've seen a lot of questions that couple serial ports and scales.  Very cool!

Answer (score 6):

Since the device is continuously sending information through the serial port, you probably want to set up a timer and take a look at what's coming down the connection without blocking the main thread.

First, I am going to point you to [Win32::GUI::Tutorial::Part4](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::GUI::Tutorial::Part4#Timers) where timers are discussed.

Run the following example using `perl.exe`, not `wperl.exe` because the output goes to the console:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package My::GUI;

use strict; use warnings;

use Win32::GUI();

sub new { bless {} => shift }

sub initialize { # very quick and dirty example
    my $self = shift;

    $self->{window} = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
        -name => 'Main',
        -title => 'Test',
        -onTerminate => sub { -1 },
        -onTimer => sub { $self->onTimer(@_) },
    );

    $self->{timer} = $self->{window}->AddTimer(Timer => 0);
    return $self;
}

sub run {
    my $self = shift;

    my $window = $self->{window};
    $window->Show;
    $window->SetRedraw(1);
    $self->{timer}->Interval(1000);
    Win32::GUI::Dialog();
}

# poll serial port here, don't block
sub onTimer { warn time - $^T, "\n"; return; }

package main;

use strict; use warnings;

My::GUI->new->initialize->run;
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> gui
1
2
3
4
5
6
Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)
```

Now, regarding the choice between [Win32::SerialPort](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::SerialPort) versus [Win32::CommPort](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::CommPort) and which methods depends on the specs of the scale on the other end of the connection.